Handling Zigbee leave reliably
1. Leave request
I want to remove a ZED from the network from the coordinator. The target ZED can be at any depth, not only a direct child. If the target ZED is unavailable, I need its parent to remove the nbr table entry.
From what I understand:

Local nlme-leave.request isn't enough, since it only works for devices present in nbr table.
mgmt_leave_req with target nwk&ieee isn't enough, since it would fail if the target device is offline.

So what is the reliable flow to request a ZED to leave?
2. Handling leave indication
I have a full device table on the coordinator application. It includes direct child devices as well as nested in the network. How to garbage collect entries in this table, in case a ZED/ZR was reset and I've missed its Leave report command?
Can I somehow ask all routers in the network about their unexpired children once in a while?
I've tried using mgmt_lqi_req with paging recursively but some of the devices just vanish from the results randomly, but still are available on NWK.
